Computation timed out error in Google Earth Engine
I'm new to GEE.
I am trying to use random forest classification to identify solar panels in a region of Brazil using a Landsat 8 median image and derived bands. However, the dataset seems to be too large for GEE to handle, as I encounter a computation timeout error running the classification lines.
The region covers approximately 148,000 km² and I've seen others run even larger areas.
Do you see errors in my code that could cause this problem or any potential solution?
// Load Landsat 8 surface reflectance image collection for the year 2023
var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
                .filterDate('2023-01-31', '2023-12-31')
                .filterBounds(Ceara)
                .map(function(image) {
                  // Apply cloud mask
                  var cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(3).int(); 
                  var cloudsBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(5).int(); 
                  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
                  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                              .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
                  return image.updateMask(mask);
                });

// Select the necessary bands (reflective and thermal)
var bands = ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7'
, 'ST_B10'];

// Create a median composite image
var medianComposite = landsat8.select(bands).median().clip(Ceara);

// Isolate the median Bands
var medianBand5 = landsat8.select('SR_B5').median()
.clip(sertao).toInt32();

// Compute and add multiple bands (NDVI, NDBI, MNDWI)
var NDVI = medianComposite.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4'])
.rename('NDVI');
var NDBI = medianComposite.normalizedDifference(['SR_B6', 'SR_B5'])
.rename('NDBI');
var MNDWI = medianComposite.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B6'])
.rename('MNDWI');

var SpectralIndices = ee.Image([NDVI, NDBI, MNDWI]);
print('SpectralIndices',SpectralIndices);
// Generate texture bands through the GLCM matrix function with 1 to 15 window sizes
var texture7 = medianBand5.glcmTexture({size: 7});
var texture9 = medianBand5.glcmTexture({size: 9});
var texture11 = medianBand5.glcmTexture({size: 11});

// Select the necessary textural bands (correlation, dissimilarity, and entropy)
var texturalBands = ['SR_B5_corr', 'SR_B5_diss', 'SR_B5_ent'];
var finalTexture7 = texture7.select(texturalBands).clip(Ceara);
var finalTexture9 = texture9.select(texturalBands).clip(Ceara);
var finalTexture11 = texture11.select(texturalBands).clip(Ceara);

print('Texture_9',finalTexture9 );



// Adding the slope band
var SRTM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");
var slope = SRTM.clipToBoundsAndScale({
  geometry: Ceara,
  scale: 30,  // meters
});

// Formation of an image made of all the classification bands
var ClassificationVariables = ee.Image([medianComposite, NDVI, NDBI,
MNDWI, finalTexture9, slope]);

print('Classification Variables', ClassificationVariables);


// Unification of the training points and splitting between the training and the validation points
var polygons = PV.merge(No_PV);
var polygons = polygons.filterBounds(Ceara);
var sample = polygons.randomColumn();
var trainingsample = sample.filter('random <= 0.75');
var validationsample = sample.filter('random > 0.75');

// Specify the source image (which contains the bands for the classification) and the property to classify
var training = ClassificationVariables.sampleRegions({
    collection: trainingsample,
    properties: ['Class'],
    scale: 30
});

var validation = ClassificationVariables.sampleRegions({
    collection: validationsample,
    properties: ['Class'],
    scale: 30
});

//print(training, 'Training sample');
//print(validation, 'Validation sample');


// Train the classifier
var RFclassifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(200)
.train(training, 'Class');

// Classify the image
var Classified = ClassificationVariables.classify(RFclassifier)
.clip(Ceara);

print(Classified, 'Classified');
Map.addLayer(Classified);




Does it run on a smaller study area?

There are no information on the complexity of the region geometry or the complexity and number of training data you are using, which makes any answer a speculation! But looking at your code, excessive use of clip is likely causing the poor performance.
See here about using clipToBoundsAndScale

Caution: providing a large or complex collection as the geometry
argument can result in poor performance. Collating the geometry of
collections does not scale well; use the smallest collection (or
geometry) that is required to achieve the desired outcome.

and here about clip

Using clip() unnecessarily will increase computation time. Avoid
clip() unless it's necessary to your analysis. If you're not sure,
don't clip.

Using random large region and toy training data, the code works fine when clip is not used till the end. See revised code here

Thanks for the answer. I simplified the region of interest and used the clip and clipToBounds functions as you advised, and it worked perfectly
